# What does the small circle symbol mean on the compass/HUD?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Sometimes the compass and HUD will show a small circle as a marker. There are two in this image, to the left and right of the crosshair and on the compass. They look like a circle with a smaller circle inside it, like a target:

[image: Small circles on the compass and HUD]

They can be difficult to find in the world and don't always correspond to waypoints or other markers - I found one in the centre of a depot, but have had trouble finding others.

Comment: Is this the green circle with the question mark or the white dots?

Comment: Are you talking about the small white circle with a dot in it that's off to the right?

Comment: I mean the two circles with a smaller circle inside that look a bit like targets. Edited the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a "Custom Waypoint". It is marked by looking/scanning a structure with your Zoom Visor. You probably set it accidentally as I did the first couple of times. To clear the mark, go to the waypoint and scan it. It's a handy way to mark a trading post so you can find it again as you mine and fill up.

Answer (score 11):

There are two types of white dots that can show up on your HUD.

If the white dots are only visible while holding your scanner for 3+ seconds, then they are locations where fauna will spawn, but are too far to tell if they've already been discovered or not.

If the white dots are always visible and do not pulsate, then they are points of interest that you've scanned - something that can be interacted with in some way, such as an Exo-Suit upgrade.

Comment: This is the correct answer. There doesn't seem to be a way to remove them either (on PC at least).